# How to give shadow to ExpansionPanelRadio widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm using ExpansionPanelList.radio to show a bunch of FAQs on the screen. As the children property only accepts a List of ExpansionPanel widgets, I can't give shadow to the ExpansionPanelRadio widget. Is there any method to give it a shadow like so:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
class FaqsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  FaqsScreen({super.key});

  final List<int> _faqData = List.generate(5, (index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
              elevation: 0,
              expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: _faqData
                  .map(
                    (faq) => ExpansionPanelRadio(
                      value: _faqData.indexOf(faq),
                      canTapOnHeader: true,
                      headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) => ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        title: Text('1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text?'),
                      ),
                      body: Column(
                        children: [
                          Divider(),
                          Text(
                            'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but you can try wrapping the `ExpensionPanelRadio` widget with a `Container` widget and then apply a `BoxDecoration` with a `BoxShadow` on its decoration property. You could use this source for some help https://codeonwards.com/how-to-add-shadows-to-widgets-in-flutter/.

Comment: Can't. ExpansionPanelList.radio only accepts a list of ExpansionPanel widgets.

Comment: My apologies, I read your question too quickly, applying it on the `ListTile` is also not doing the trick right?

Comment: No that does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ExpansionTile instead of ExpansionPanelRadio

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiNaj.png)

and here is the sample code :

```
 class FaqsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  FaqsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<FaqsScreen> createState() => _FaqsScreenState();
}

class _FaqsScreenState extends State<FaqsScreen> {
  final List<int> _faqData = List.generate(5, (index) => index);

  int _expandedIndex = -1; // all tiles close at beginning

  void _handleExpansion(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (_expandedIndex == index) {
        _expandedIndex = -1; // if the same tile, then close it
      } else {
        _expandedIndex = index;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: Column(
              children: _faqData
                  .map(
                    (faq) => Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                              blurRadius: 10),
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: -2,
                            blurRadius: 5,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: ExpansionTile(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        onExpansionChanged: (expanded) {
                          _handleExpansion(faq);
                        },
                        initiallyExpanded: _expandedIndex == faq,
                        controller: ExpansionTileController(),
                        title: Text('1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text?'),
                        children: [
                          Divider(),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 8),
                            child: Text(
                              'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need the radio functionality. So when user taps on a new faq, the faq that was previously open automatically closes.

Comment: edit the code for desired behavior. Also you can use AnimatedContainer if you need animation during behavior

Comment: or if you still want to use radio, then simply change the elevation property. Elevation property of ExpansionPanelList.radio takes 0 between (faq.length-1). So care if you do not have static amount faq otherwise it will crash